# JS accordions not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have a website with some JS accordions on it, they do not open, however they do on codepen. I have looked in the console on chrome and I go no error messages. However when I looked in the console in Firefox I get the following error message 7 times:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://xurbia.tk/alpha/homebeta.html failed. homebeta.html
>
> All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. homebeta.html

I have no idea what is going on here so any help is much appreciated.

The relevant code for one of the accordions is as follows:

```
<dt>
  <a href="#accordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion2" class="accordion-title accordionTitle js-accordionTrigger">
    <img src="http://xurbia.tk/alpha/pictures/Play_button_next_stop_music_pause.png" height=40px class="pull-left"/>
    Detox
    <img src="http://xurbia.tk/alpha/pictures/Play_button_next_stop_music_pause.png" height=40px class="pull-right"/></a>
</dt>
<dd class="accordion-content accordionItem is-collapsed" id="accordion2" aria-hidden="true">
  <img src="http://xurbia.tk/alpha/pictures/accordian%20pictures/Detox.PNG" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <audio controls>
    <source src="" type="audio/wav" width="100%">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</dd>
```

The full code can be found here:
http://xurbia.tk/alpha/Stackoverflow.txt

Here is the code-pen where I started making the accordions:
http://codepen.io/shardros/pen/OyJqzj

Here is the website that they do not work on:
http://xurbia.tk/alpha/homebeta.html

Comment: After comparing the source of the 2 html files, I notice there a very little differences. The only differences that I am seeing are: the ads, the Viewport and the Meta tags.

I'm curious, could it be there is a conflict with that ads you've put in?

Comment: Thank you in now works. I don't think that the ads have any conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the live site, your JavaScript is written using the **module pattern**...which is good.

This pattern uses an **immediately invoked function expression** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

This means that as soon as the function is declared, it is invoked (and executes).

Because you have this script in the `<head>` section of your page, it executes before the DOM has loaded (before your actual page loads).

This means that your JavaScript tries to add event listeners and manipulate elements that **do not yet exist**!

In order to fix this, move the `<script>` tag out of `<head>` and place it as the last element **within** the `<body>` tag.

This will have the effect of the JavaScript being invoked **after** all necessary elements have been created.

(Your example works in Codepen because they execute the JavaScript after the DOM has loaded)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your JS is executing before the page is loaded. It's good practice to insert your JS at the end of the `<body>` element to [improve page load speed](http://Best%20Practices%20for%20Speeding%20Up%20Your%20Web%20Site).

You could also use an event to fire after the page loads like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //Page has loaded
}
```